# Better way of handling Tap Gesture on Lists

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a 1 count tap gesture and 2 count tap gesture on rows of a list view.

Currently I'm achieving this by expanding the contents of the rows to fill the entire width and height, by changing the row insets with `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())` and adding an `HStack` with a `Spacer` inside. As seen below:

My `ListRow` View, which serves to attempt to fill out the the entire rows' width and height. (With a red border for debugging):

```
struct ListRow<Content: View> : View {
    let content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            content()
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .border(Color.red)
    }
}
```

And here's a snippet of one of the two places I'm using a list with my `ListRow`:

```
List(selection: $selectedItem) {
    Section(header: Text("Favourites")) {
        ForEach($sidebarItems, id: \.self) { $item in
            ListRow {
                FileLabel(URL(string: item.path)!, size: 14, text: item.text)
            }.gesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                selectedItem = item
                fileState.updatePath(path: item.path)
            }).listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        }
    }
}.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
```

A few issues happen here, which both feels hacky and incorrect to do.

1. I have to manually select the row when the content is tapped.
2. I actually manually have to focus the list, if it's not actually focused when clicking a row, otherwise the selection is a very faint color.
3. The contents aren't actually expanding to the leading and trailing edges of the row, no matter if I give my `EdgeInsets` negative values (This just results in the contents getting clipped, rather than expanding to the edge).
4. Clicking the areas outside of the red border (seen below) results in the row being selected, but the tap action not firing.

[image: Image showing the issues described above]

Preferably I'd love if there was a way to listen for tap gestures on a list and get the row that was tapped. It would fix having to manually reimplement features that the List already has built-in and lowering the risk of introducing bugs + it just feels like the right way to do it, unfortunately I haven't been able to find other ways of implementing this, other than creating an `HStack` with a `Spacer`.

**EDIT:**
I'm curious as to how `NavigationLink` works as no matter where you click, or if you navigate using your keyboard, it'll actually trigger the navigation. Makes me think there's some kind of binding or event fired?

Comment: afaik what you're after can't actually be done nicely with `List` at the moment. The issue with the selection highlighting extending outside of border I suspect is `List` reserving space on the edge for drag handles and can't be changed. Having to manually set the selection is bc the attached gesture is operating at a higher priority than the one `List` uses and it doesn't automatically feed through. Fwiw, easiest solution would be to use something else other than double tap to trigger events. If double tap is a must have, then it will be far less painful to use `VStack` instead of `List`.

Comment: @shufflingb That's really unfortunate, I was really hoping to be able to use Apple's own components to make as native of an experience as possible, without having to write my own components with all the accessibility features that Apple provides out of the box.

Comment: Been thinking about issue further. And fwiw, the inability to do double tap in a list appears to be more likely a bug rather than any intentional omission on A's part (they're using same action in modern macOS Notes app). So while it's unlikely to help in the short-term, it would be worth submitting a Feedback ticket to A - particularly about the highlighting outside of the frame issue - as it'll have a reasonable chance of being fixed.

Comment: Your hunch is correct, this is standard behaviour, it can be achieved through `NavigationSplitView`. The same scenario has been explained in https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10054. There is even a sample project at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/bringing_robust_navigation_structure_to_your_swiftui_app. Always go through What's new in SwiftUI every year and decide what you want to go in detail

Comment: @shufflingb I'll give that a try, note that I am able to double tap however, just that it's not directly connected to the list, but rather the individual views that I've got in my list.

Comment: @user1046037 Yes, I'm aware of `NavigationSplitView`, however, I might want to execute some code, rather than navigate, which doesn't seem to be possible with `NavigationSplitView`?

Comment: Do you want a sidebar and detail view and when side bar item is selected detail displayed? And along with detail displayed do you want some code executed?